# Set the corner radius of the content border

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, cornerradius

I want to have a window with the border radius of the content border is 5. Exactly like on the picture:

[image]

How can I do this With C# and WPF ? Is there any way to do this with Windows API?

Comment: Do you looking for [Border.CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius.aspx) property?

Comment: All the windows default corner radius are same, I want to set it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do this work :

First I needed WindowsAPICodePack, I download it from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/
  After downloading it, I Extracted it and found the necessary DLLs in /binaries folder . There are two DLLs I I needed :

> Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll

Then I created an WPF Application in Visual Studio (.NET 3.5), And added these two dlls in my application

> Right click on refrences in Solution Explorer tab > Add Refrence

then I changed the MainWindow XAML codes :

```
<WindowsAPICodePackShell:GlassWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:WindowsAPICodePackPresentation="clr-namespace:Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Controls.WindowsPresentationFoundation;assembly=Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell"
xmlns:WindowsAPICodePackShell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell"
Title="WPF AeroGlass Demo" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="GlassWindow_Loaded">
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Gray"></Border>
</WindowsAPICodePackShell:GlassWindow>
```

And my MainWindow.xaml.cs codes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// 
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// 
    public partial class MainWindow : GlassWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GlassWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetAeroGlassTransparency();
        }
    }
}
```

And When I run the app :
[image]

Answer (score 5):

WPF is rendered in standard operating system windows, if you need to change that style you have to change the so called windows chrome. The basic is to create a transparent hosting window and draw all inside it by using WPF so you can drive whatever you want and of course the corner radius too, [have a look here for an example](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/10/12/creating-border-less-windows-in-wpf.aspx). [Something more complete in this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library).
If you want to search yourself, the keywords *wpf custom chrome* would help.

Comment: I don't want to create a WPF Style, I just want to use the default window style but change some of it's properties(In this case border radius). Just like the Google Chrome tabs which are in the default window theme.

Comment: you cant use wpf to change something that is not driven by WPF, you can dig deeper but you evetually arrive at the point I suggested.

Comment: Thanks Felice Pollano, I just meant that I want to do this work with Windows API